call index function in controller not work
I have written two routes in the web.php file:
Route::get('taskmanager/sessions', [SessionsController::class, 'index'])->name('sessions.index');
Route::get('taskmanager/sessions/create', [SessionsController::class, 'create'])->name('sessions.create');

And in the controller, I have called both as follows:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SessionsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        dd('index');
    }
    public function create()
    {
        dd('create');
    }
}

by typing the address taskmanager/sessions/create the create message is displayed But the address taskmanager/sessions, index does not appear! It seems like a small mistake, but I can't find it

Everything is fine but do one thing please clear the route php artisan route:clear

I did, but it didn't work

What happens if you change your uri of index ?
Also sometimes changing the position of route helps too.

The issue is that it does not enter the index function at all, but it enters the create function.

What do you get when you run php artisan route:list?
